# How to diagnose this memory dump?

Tags: .net, debugging, memory-leaks

I'd like to get some pointers on how to diagnose a dump of a memory leak; I'm not sure what to make of the information presented. Here is the summary of DebugDiag:

```
Type of Analysis Performed   Memory Pressure Analysis 
Machine Name    
Operating System   Windows 7Service Pack 1 
Number Of Processors    
Process ID   15120 
Process Image   [***.exe]
System Up-Time   7 day(s) 24:49:54 
Process Up-Time   3 day(s) 23:03:40 
Processor Type   X64 
Process Bitness   32-Bit 

Virtual Memory Summary

Size of largest free VM block   1,19 MBytes 
Free memory fragmentation   99,3% 
Free Memory   169,87 MBytes   (8,29% of Total Memory) 
Reserved Memory   1,05 GBytes   (52,43% of Total Memory) 
Committed Memory   804,26 MBytes   (39,27% of Total Memory) 
Total Memory   2 GBytes 
Largest free block at   0x00000000`393f0000 

Virtual Memory Details

Virtual Allocations  1,37 GBytes 
Loaded Modules  268,4 MBytes 
Threads  206,76 MBytes 
System 4 KBytes
Page Heaps 0 Bytes 
Native Heaps  1,56 MBytes

Virtual Allocation Summary

Reserved memory   894,86 MBytes 
Committed memory   506,48 MBytes 
Mapped memory   146,43 MBytes 
Reserved block count   1251 blocks 
Committed block count   2677 blocks 
Mapped block count   82 blocks
```

The application died with a "System.IO.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command." trying to create a MemoryMappedView. It does create and destroy memory mapped files repeatedly during execution.

I can see that there is very high free memory fragmentation (99,3%) but there's also very little free memory (170MB) so I'm wondering if the issue is a leak or fragmentation.

Comment: Sure.  Having a largest block of only 1.17MB available is the killer.  The reserved memory amount is extraordinarily high, hard to guess how you did that.  MMFs could certainly be the source of the problem, use a good memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Dump does not show anything suspicious about the memory of you application. It looks that the application just normally consumed all the available memory. You can try to go deeper and analyze the details of the .net memory by using one of the memory profiles, like WinDbg. See my article for details on how to do it: http://alexatnet.com/articles/net-memory-management-and-garbage-collector

Comment: There's nothing suspicious about a free memory fragmentation of 99,3%?

Comment: Practically, if the fragmentation will be 0% then your application most likely fails after a few more iteration of the algorithm that consumes the memory - it consumed almost 2 Gb already so what will stop it from eating 169,87 Mb more even if they would be in one block? So my recommendation will be to check why you have so many objects in the memory and probably you will find a memory leak. If you did not and this is expected behavior then most likely you will need to change the memory utilization strategy. For example, reuse the object or intensively call GC.Collect().

Comment: BTW, such fragmentation most likely the tails of the Large Object Heap segments. Size of the LOH segment is 16Mb, so for 1.8Gb there may be 100 of them. So you may have 100 tails. If each is 1.6 Mb long (the size depends on the average size of the allocated object in the heap), this will give you 99% fragmentation.